# BOSH CloudFoundry AWS bootstrap wrong characters in generated password

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

"bundle exec cf bootstrap aws" command creates the following configuration in cf-aws.yml

batch:
      username: all153_Makayalam's
      password: cafÃ©s3352-Deann's

and then it can't parse this file and throws the error: 
.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:205:in`parse_stream'
        from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'

any ideas how to regenerate the password?

Answer (score 0):

The password is taken from cf-shared-secrets.yml  and can be changed there